# Pergunta no meta fechada como fora do escopo tem link para a central de ajuda do site principal

Tags: bug, status-aceito, perguntas-fechadas, meta

Recentemente, uma pergunta acerca de preferências de uso de linguagens de programação foi postada aqui no meta. Esse é o tipo de coisa que está no escopo do site principal, mas definitivamente não é do escopo do meta.

Entretanto, além de ter sido postada no lugar errado, essa pergunta também era opinativa e por isso foi fechada ao invés de ser migrada. A seguinte caixa foi adicionada abaixo da pergunta:

[image: caixa adicionada]

O texto em vermelho escrito "[central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)" é um link para https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help. O texto [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) é um link para a home do site principal (http://pt.stackoverflow.com).

Ocorre que o texto diz que foi fechada como fora do escopo e o link manda para páginas onde o usuário poderá ver qual que é o escopo do site principal, e não o escopo do meta. Um usuário iniciante poderia não entender isso e ao acessar o link, seria levado a páginas que dizem que o escopo deste site (o meta) é sobre programação, e portanto ele não entenderia porque está fora do escopo.

Sugiro mudar este link para ir a algum lugar que explique qual que é o escopo, o propósito e a finalidade do meta.

Aliás, o segundo link "[central de ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)" dá em uma página mais específica (https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Entretanto, esse link redireciona para https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions - ou seja, para algo acerca do escopo do site principal.

E nem estou entrando no mérito de o link ser para uma página genérica de ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help ao invés de ir para uma página mais específica https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Realmente, o link que me parece correto é o [whats-meta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) (que não tem nada haver com whatsapp :p)

Comment: O Meta não tem uma Central de Ajuda própria, com seu `on-topic`, `closed-questions`, etc. O que dá pra fazer, como o @GuilhermeNascimento sugeriu, é trocar o link para o `whats-meta`. Vou ver com os devs.